# Error function routine

Tags: php

Pls what is the best approach considering (performance, security etc.) to implement an error function. Something in the line of ..

```
function trap_errors($error_code, $parametrs...)
{
$error_code = array => ('1001 = Error description1', '1002 = Error description2',..etc.
)


}
```

I dont know if the above makes sense. Any pointers?..

Comment: I see no sense in such a function at all. What is your goal? What you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Until you give more details as "Col. Shrapnel" requests, let me plug an Open Source project I'm working on that collects errors, sends them to a central reporting app, filters them, emails staff and creates tickets. The ticket system is at http://elastik.sourceforge.net/ and you want to look at the ErrorReportingService module (look in the general documentation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an (global) error handler:

```
function myErrorHandler($type, $msg)
{
    echo $type . ' ' . $msg;
}

set_error_handler("myErrorHandler");
```

And trigger an error by your own which arrives the upper defined function:

```
trigger_error("This is an error!", E_USER_ERROR);
```

Look [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php) to see the list of error types.

**This catches each error in PHP: your ones or the system errors, e.g.**

Comment: Thanks but is it possible to convert the error type to an understandable info? Instead of 256 say "System could not process your input.."

Comment: You can use a converter function where convert the constants to a string by using a switch block.

Comment: @Frank you don't need such conversion at all. You have completely misunderstood error handling. You don't have to explain every system error to the user. There are only 2 options - 503 and 404. thats ALL